# Facebook oAuth Authentication Security

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using the JavaScript SDK and making a login request, once I receive the request response from Facebook that states the user is "Connected" ho can I be assured that this request was not hijacked?

Facebook provides an app secret for use in validating the response, but in the examples for authentication the app secret is never requested.

I am looking for further examples of using the JavaScript SDK or C# SDK to securely authenticate facebook users.

If I don't understand the app secret or oAuth correctly, please feel free to advise and explain why the app secret is not needed, but from the documentation I've read it sounds necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The app secret is only used *server-side* to very that a response is authentic. It can't be used client-side (ie: in JavaScript) because that would require storing the app secret itself in your JavaScript code which would entirely defeat the purpose of the secret (ie., it would no longer be a secret).

So, yes, your JavaScript requests can be hijacked, but it doesn't really matter. As long as you use your secret for server-side requests (for example, updating a MySQL database) you should be fine.